# send custom RequestBody from POST request to an external GET request in java

Tags: java, spring, post, get

I'm setting up a rest service (in a microservices scenario) with multi-threaderd post request and I need to differentiate the RequestBody delivery, for example:

`{obj0, obj1, obj2, obj3}`

First three obj are correctly forwarder on a kafka queue but now I want to add new obj (`obj3`) and separate his delivery to send it on an another external rest service.
This external GET service will receive obj3 (that are just 2 strings) to valorize his PathVariable and trigger some other algorithms.
How can I achive this result?
In my doExecute() method I've some code like this:

```
for (String element : bodyElements) {
  String[] singleElement = element.split(",");

        if (obj1 || obj2 || obj3){
          ...do something;
          }else{
           ...forward obj3 to other REST service
          }
```

Any help is appreciate, thanks!

Comment: You can use RestTemplate object to contact with external web services

Comment: Can you explain better, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will answer your question

```
HttpEntity body = new HttpEntity(postBody,headers);
new RestTemplate().exchange("http://service-url",HttpMethod.POST,body,String.class);
```

This is just an example of rest template. If you want to do GET call just replace `HttpMethod.POST` to `HttpMethod.GET` and pass body as null

Comment: Tried now but not working.I need to pass a custom body so I've set it but I get:

 org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Comment: Add Content-Type header in headers to a value that service is receiving like "application/json"

Comment: HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

HttpEntity body = new HttpEntity(payload, headers);

...but got same error

Comment: is a single JSON mocked in a test String like:
"{\n" +
                "    \"attribute1\": \"value\",\n" +
                "    \"attribute2\": \"value\",\n" + "}";

Comment: Have you tried adding accept header too as per your desired response type

Comment: yes, I've used "headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));" ....... and also "headers.setAcceptCharset(Arrays.asList(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));"

Comment: Are you sure the api you are hitting is accepting application/json and response you receiving in same format as your accept header value

Comment: my dest api produces text/plain so I've also set content type (MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) but error remains

Comment: If your api produces text/plain set Accept header value to text/plain not content-type

Comment: Nope, not working!
I voted anyway because I know that your solution is correct...mine is just a special case

Comment: Thanks mate, but iam just curious what's going on

Comment: I'm working to fix this problem cause I'm under custom framework and I need to read documentation deeply. I hope to find solution "quickly" so can I post the fix

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: I've found solution! Because the custom framework, I've handle this request using custom RestConnector with request and response transformer like RequestTransformer<String, Obj> which in turn implement another transformer like <INPUT, DTO> so I had to handle the data better than normal usage of RestTemplate.
Thanks for support @Ravi Teja !!!